# switching between screens

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm using GNU screen just recently. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to switch between screen. for example to map it to alt+left arrow and alt+right arrow ?

Comment: Easier than what? What command are you using to switch screens right now?

Comment: FYI, the different pseudo-terminals within `screen` are normally called `windows`.  This might help you when reading `man screen` or other documentation.

Comment: Thanks guys for answers. Actually my main problem is that i can not map alt+arrows, i don't know why.
@vstrien showed me the right answer but not with the right keys
sorry to be so hard to please...

Answer (score 2):

You can bind keys in screen settings (.screenrc) using the bindkey function. For example:

```
# Bind F11 and F12 (NOT F1 and F2) to previous and next screen window
bindkey -k F1 prev
bindkey -k F2 next
```

(this example can be found at http://www.pixelbeat.org/lkdb/screen.html)